Loop-space functor on cohomology
For a pointed space $X$ and an Abelian group $G$, the loop-space functor induces a homomorphism $\omega:H^n(X,G)\to H^{n-1}(\Omega X,G)$.
More concretely, $\omega$ is given by the Puppe sequence
$$\cdots \to \Omega X \overset{\omega f}{\to} K(G,n\!-\!1) \to Mf \to X \overset{f}{\to} K(G,n)\,.$$
Equivalently, $\omega$ can also be defined as the pullback of the evaluation map $\Sigma\Omega X {\to} X$, i.e.,
$$[X, K(G,n)]\overset{\omega}{\to}[\Sigma\Omega X, K(G,n)]\simeq[\Omega X, K(G,n\!-\!1)]\,.$$

Q1. Is $\omega$ the inverse of the transgression map in the Serre spectral sequence associated to $\Omega X\to *\to X$?
Q2. Where can I find a discussion on $\omega$'s properties, e.g., kernel and image (especially if the answer to Q1 is "no")?

Have you tried Serre's thesis (published as "Homologie singulière des espaces fibrés" Ann of Math 1951)?

Thank you @DaveBenson, but I'm not good at French...

If you are willing to read a little French, look at page 434 of Serre's "Homologie singuliere des espaces fibres" (1951).
For an exercise in English, with a hint, try Exercise 2 on page 155 in Mosher and Tangora's "Cohomology Operations and Applications in Homotopy Theory" (1968).
For a more detailed reference, look at Proposition 6.10 in McCleary's "User's Guide to Spectral Sequences" (1985/2001).
See also Proof of the ''trangression theorem'' and On the transgression in the Serre spectral sequence here on MathOverflow.

Thanks! I'll check the details there.

For Q2, when searching it might be useful to know two things:

The map $\omega$ is often called the cohomology suspension (not to be confused with the suspension isomorphism in cohomology!), and
Elements of the kernel of $\omega$ are precisely the elements of category weight 2.

To expand on 2., as explained in Cornea-Lupton-Oprea-Tanré's book on Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, the evaluation map $\Sigma\Omega X\to X$ is equivalent to the Ganea fibration $G_1 X\to X$. The homotopy fibre of both maps is $\Omega X * \Omega X\simeq \Sigma \Omega X \wedge \Omega X$, which is $2k$-connected if $X$ is $k$-connected. This gives a range in which $\omega$ is an isomorphism, from the Serre exact sequence.
Note also that any cup product of reduced cohomology classes is the kernel of $\omega$ (obviously, since cup products vanish in a suspension). But the kernel can also contain indecomposable classes, e.g. triple Massey products.
Regarding the image of $\omega$, I'd be willing to bet that it's exactly the transgressive elements.
